# Implode column of private values from an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, oop, private-members

I have an array of objects and I want to implode a specific private property from each object to form a delimited string.

I am only interested on one of the properties of that array. I know how to iterate the data set via `foreach()` but is there a functional-style approach?

```
$ids = "";
foreach ($itemList as $item) {
    $ids = $ids.$item->getId() . ",";
}
// $ids = "1,2,3,4"; <- this already returns the correct result
```

My class is like this:

```
class Item {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id=$id;
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    
    //function getters.....
}
```

Sample data:

```
$itemList = [
    new Item(1, "Item 1"),
    new Item(2, "Item 2"),
    new Item(3, "Item 3"),
    new Item(4, "Item 4")
];
```

Comment: Do you actually need "cheaper", as opposed to clear, obvious code? If not, just go for the loop.

Comment: When I say "cheaper" I mean resource friendly.

Comment: Probably the most expensive resource is you, and future maintainers. Keep the code as simple and readable as possible, and if you find you need to optimise you can always come back when you've benchmarked and pinpointed the problem areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array_map` before you `implode`:

```php
$ids = implode(",", array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item->getId();
}, $itemList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You've "yatta-yatta"ed your getter scripting, so I'll demonstrate two functional style approaches for two getter approaches.

1. If the class contains an explicitly named method: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Fqs89))

   ```
   public function getId()
   {
       return $this->id;
   }
   ```

   then you can use 2 cycles:

   ```
   echo implode(',', array_map(fn($obj) => $obj->getId(), $itemList));
   ```

   or 1 cycle with a conditional:

   ```
   echo array_reduce(
            $itemList,
            fn($result, $obj) => $result . ($result ? ',' : '') . $obj->getId()
        );
   ```
2. If the class contains the magic method `__get()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PBtHA))

   ```
   public function __get($prop)
   {
       return $this->$prop;
   }
   ```

   then you can use 2 cycles:

   ```
   echo implode(',', array_map(fn($obj) => $obj->id, $itemList));
   ```

   or 1 cycle with a conditional:

   ```
   echo array_reduce(
            $itemList,
            fn($result, $obj) => $result . ($result ? ',' : '') . $obj->id
        );
   ```

Answer (score -3):

You can simply use `$ids = implode(',',$itemList);`

Comment: That is if the __toString returns $id. The __toString return a different thing